# After changing the package name in android studio, I can't access the camera in my application. When I restore the package name, it works fine

Tags: android, android-camera, package-name

I changed the package name in android studio, I don't get any error, but my application does not open the camera, when I click on the camera, the application closes

Comment: hey, can you please share your code to open the camera?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: When I restore the package name, my application still works fine, but as soon as I change the package name, I have a problem with camare access.

Comment: I didn't ask for the `permissions` or `feature` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Okay, leave the code, just look for the hardcoded package name used in your whole project and replace it with the new one or try using `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` or `${applicationId}` accordingly.

Comment: can you help me if i send you the zip file only the package name will change please help me i couldn't solve the problem

Comment: Okay, please share the link to the zip.

Comment: https://www.technicdude.in/how-to-create-pdf-converter-app/        package name will be woynapp.wsann  Just changing the package name is enough for me, I would appreciate it if you send the zip file to mevluttuncer0334@gmail after changing the package name.

Comment: did you solve the problem MojoJojo

Comment: Hey, I shared the project zip with you, please check.

Comment: thank you very much mojoJojo for solving the problem